# Nested repeaters does not respect z values

Tags: qt, qml

I have two repeaters, one is nested inside of the other.
There are two Rectangles;

```
Repeater {
    model: x

    Rectangle {
        id: alwaysOnBottom
        z: -1
        ..
    }

    Repeater {
        z: 100
        model: y

        Rectangle {
            id: alwaysOnTop
            z: 100
        }
    }
}
```

I always want the second rectangle two be on top of the first one.
However, other items just does not respect their z value and, say second item's first rectangle overdraws the first item's second rectangle.

Comment: What's **x** and **y**, could you provide full part of qml code?

Comment: [z](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) property works for sibling items, not for all the scene.  In your code `alwaysOnBottom` and `alwaysOnTop` are not.